# easiest scriptable way to change PostgreSQL user authentication method

Tags: postgresql

As described in the PostgreSQL wiki (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Client_Authentication) I can edit the `pg_hba.conf` file to set the authentication method for a user to "trust".

Is there any way to set this method with any scriptable command (possibly `ALTER`) instead of editing the configuration file manually?

(I'm using PostgreSQL-9.3, in case it matters)

Comment: No, psql is a database client, not a text editor for pg_hba.conf. In version 9.3 (and older) it's not possible to edit pg_hba.conf using SQL. In 9.4 (in Beta at the moment) you can change postgresql.conf using SQL, but not pg_hba.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how bad you want to do it, how much control you have over the system :)

How about a tactic like this...
Read the file with an fdw:

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER file_fdw_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_server;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE pghba (
username text,
pass text,
uid int4,
gid int4,
gecos text,
home text,
shell text
) SERVER file_server
OPTIONS (format 'text', filename current_setting('hba_file'), delimiter E'\t', null '');
```

Parse the contents with SQL (exercise left for the OP) and write back out to file with

```
COPY () TO current_setting('pghba_file')
```

statement.

Reload the configuration file with:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

This is obviously not a complete working example, it's more of a strategy that can get you where you want to go.  That is, if you want to go there that badly.

Comment: I begin to understand the scope of the problem; +1 for educational :)